# Yielding from redux saga with a promise return

Tags: javascript, promise, redux, generator, redux-saga

I can't get `yield` to work with promises code. When I use `yield` with a function that directly resolves a return value, it all works. But when I use yield with a proxy function, that returns another function with a promise - it stops working.

What's wrong? This is the sample code:

```
const fetchRequest = (payload) => {
    return new API.user().fetch(payload);
};

const fetchRequestFull = (payload) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (payload) resolve({'response'});
    });
};

function* fetchUser(action) {
    try {
        const userData = yield call(new API.user().fetch, action.payload); // doesnt work
        const userDataOther = yield call(fetchRequest, action.payload); // doesnt work
        const userDataYetAnother = yield call(fetchRequestFull, action.payload); // works
        // ...
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({
            type: LOGOUT,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide fetch method code

Comment: it should return a promise